# Video Editing using AVFoundation in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

1. Is it possible to add time stamp on the video screen while recording a video using camera?
2. Can we add timestamp on existing video's screen and remove audio from existing video?

I have searched over the internet, but couldn't find a clue, any guidance with reference tutorials please ?

Thanks

Comment: You have pasted the link of my question

Comment: "For removing audio you can check this question. OP has problem" here you have given link of the question where you are giving comments right now, you haven't pasted the link of the question you are talking about :)

Comment: Yes, would you click it please and see which page comes up

Comment: I am getting this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118268/video-editing-using-avfoundation-in-objective-c

and this link is my question's link

Comment: +1 Oooppss really sorry, I must be blind [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118559/how-to-fix-video-orientation-issue-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided sample for video editing. You can check that.
The AVEditDemo sample is in the WWDC 2010 sample code pack

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to process vide while recording, Use GPUImage library "https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage"