# How to fix video orientation issue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avasset

I am working with an app in which user picks video from Photos and uploads it to server. As my server is .Net server , the video gets rotated. I know the reason of problem is probably same as was in case of image (you may refer my earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10601175/1030951 ) , So i googled and got a code to fix **video orientation** , I got a  code from RayWenderlich.com and modified in following way. Now my output video works fine but the video is mute. it plays but doesn't play audio. Kindly help me if I am missing something.

I pass Info dictionary of `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method

```
- (void)fix:(NSDictionary*)pobjInfoDirectory withFileName:(NSString*)pstrOutputFileName
{
    firstAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[pobjInfoDirectory objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];


    if(firstAsset !=nil)
    {
        //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
        AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

        //VIDEO TRACK
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

                MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration);

        //FIXING ORIENTATION//
        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];

        AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

        UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;

        BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;

        CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

        if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
        }        
        if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
        }
        if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
        }
        if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
        }

        CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;

        if(isFirstAssetPortrait_)
        {
            FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        }
        else
        {
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        }
        [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];

        MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];;

        AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
        MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
        MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
        MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

        AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

        exporter.outputURL=url;
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
        [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
             });
         }];
    }
}

- (void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session
{
    if(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
    {
        NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL])
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(videoExported)])
                [self.delegate videoExported];    
        }
    }       
    firstAsset = nil;
}
```

Comment: You sure it's not your iPhone that is muted?

Comment: yes , i played in photos app , it played with sound..

Comment: check this may halp you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814626/programatically-access-orientation-of-an-iphone-video

Comment: @NitinGohel , thanks but it just detects the orientation of video , i have done the same in else if ladder. My problem is the sound doesn't play. only audio plays

Comment: check it post, it's you need, say how make the video re-encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402106/how-to-correct-orientation-of-video-in-objective-c/28056569#28056569

Comment: @HarshIT, i want to merge portrait & landscape video but i can't figure it out. can join the group please.

Comment: @Vats, Sorry due to some busy schedule I was not able to reply you on time. To merge videos with such different orientations, you may need to resize the size of video frame, I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this after the `//VIDEO TRACK` part

```
        //AUDIO TRACK
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [firstAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

Comment: will it work for video as well? i mean i am facing issue with the orientation of merged videos after applying transformation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @AbdulYasin  you find solution of Orientation issue after merging??? if yes can you give me suggestion

Answer (score 2):

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:@"your video url here..." options:nil];
```

Add After `AVMutableCompositionTrack`.

set `setPreferredTransform:` set here your source video that you want to export with same orientation.

```
 // Grab the source track from AVURLAsset for example.
AVAssetTrack *assetVideoTrack = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].lastObject;

// Grab the composition video track from AVMutableComposition you already made.
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].lastObject;

// Apply the original transform.
if (assetVideoTrack && compositionVideoTrack) {
        [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform];
    }
```